# Using scipy.spatial.Delaunay in place of matplotlib.tri.Triangulation's built-in version

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, delaunay

It appears as if `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` uses a buggy and possibly incorrect implementation of Delaunay triangulation that is due to be replaced by [qHull](http://www.qhull.org/).

I'm trying to plot a trisurf using `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.plot_trisurf()` and running into a bunch of exceptions that are unhelpful (`IndexError`s and `KeyError`s mostly, with no indication of what exactly went wrong).

Since `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` already uses qHull, I was wondering if there was a way to build a `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` object for use with `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.plot_trisurf()` using scipy's implementation of Delaunay triangulation.

I've tried passing the `delaunay.points` directly to `matplotlib.tri.Triangulate` via the `triangles` parameter, but this results in a `ValueError: triangles min element is out of bounds`.

Comment: As a side not, this will be fixed in 1.4, if you can try using the current master branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html
http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/tri_api.html

So you need to pass both the points and the triangles from qhull to the `Triangulation` constructor:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial
import matplotlib
import math

import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# First create the x and y coordinates of the points.
n_angles = 20
n_radii = 10
min_radius = 0.15
radii = np.linspace(min_radius, 0.95, n_radii)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)
angles[:, 1::2] += math.pi/n_angles
x = (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten()
y = (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten()

# Create the Delaunay tessalation using scipy.spatial
pts = np.vstack([x, y]).T
tess = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(pts)

# Create the matplotlib Triangulation object
x = tess.points[:, 0]
y = tess.points[:, 1]
tri = tess.vertices # or tess.simplices depending on scipy version
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x=pts[:, 0], y=pts[:, 1], triangles=tri)

# Plotting
z = x*x + y*y
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(triang, z)
plt.show()
```

output (with matplotlib current master):
[image]

Comment: And If I have only a 2D array as input?

Answer (score -1):

@Marco was curious to know how to run this for a 2d array. I hope this would be useful. The list of vertices according to coordinates should be made an array and can be tessellated using mtri.Triangulation.
Sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri


verts = np.array([[0.6,0.8],[0.2,0.9],[0.1,-0.5],[0.2,-2]])

triang = mtri.Triangulation(verts[:,0], verts[:,1])

plt.triplot(triang, marker="o")

plt.show()`enter code here`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions with existing answers (this question is eight and a half years old). Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].